# Router do Angular 7 aparece a página que eu quero mas não tira a página anterior e fica as duas ao mesmo tempo

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routes, ui-router

Configurei meus arquivos todos corretamente eu acho, mas quando eu clico em no botão

Essa é a página de configuração do router eu coloquei a signup no array

**app-route.module.ts**

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SignupComponent } from './signup/signup.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Essa é o navbar que eu usei pra chamar a rota signup

**nav.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper header" id="home">
  <nav>
    <div class="menu-icon">
      <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="logo">
      <a class="scroll" href="#home">SHOP</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#guitars">Guitars</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="scroll" routerLink="/signup" routerLinkActive="active">SignUp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <h3 class="h3style">A guitarra do seus sonhos <br> está aqui</h3>

</div>
```

E esse é minha página que eu uso pra chamar os seletores

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<app-products></app-products>
<app-subscribe></app-subscribe>
<app-contact></app-contact>
<app-footer></app-footer>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Única coisa que acontece quando eu clico no signup na navbar é adicionar a página que eu quero abaixo da página que eu quero que saia quando eu clicar no signup alguém sabe o que tenho que fazer ?

Comment: Qual página você quer que saia ? Pelo visto você tem somente uma página que é carregada no app component `router-outlet`, o `signup`, então nenhum outro component é destruído quando o `signup` é iniciado.

Answer (score 4):

Como o Victor Henrique falou, a única página que você colocou para ser acionada por uma rota é a página de signup. Todos os outros componentes estão fixados na página principal.

Para arrumar isso, você tem que criar rotas para as outras páginas que você quer que quando você clicar em um link. Por exemplo, você poderia fazer o seguinte:

Criar um HomeComponent, NavComponent (contendo APENAS o elemento <nav>), ShopComponent, GuitarsComponent, AboutComponent e SignupComponent.

Exemplo do ***AppComponent:***

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer>
  <!-- Se o footer possuir muito conteúdo, você pode criar um component pra ele e substituir esse elemento pelo seletor do componente -->
</footer>
```

O HomeComponent deverá possuir o HTML que será carregado assim que o usuário acessar o seu site sem uma rota específica (tipo 'www.seusite.com.br/').

Dessa forma, você tem elementos que SEMPRE vão ser visíveis na página, que é o nav e o footer. O Angular vai inserir um componente diferente depois do elemento `<router-outlet>` dependendo da rota que você estiver. Aí você terá que configurar a rota dessa forma:

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent }, // Caso a rota seja 'www.seusite.com.br/'
  { path: 'About', component: AboutComponent }, // Caso a rota seja 'www.seusite.com.br/About'
  { path: 'Shop', component: ShopComponent }, // Caso a rota seja 'www.seusite.com.br/Shop'
  { path: 'Guitars', component: GuitarsComponent }, // Caso a rota seja 'www.seusite.com.br/Guitars'
  { path: 'Signup', component: SignupComponent } // Caso a rota seja 'www.seusite.com.br/signup'
];
```

Se você estiver na página Guitars e clicar em Signup, o conteúdo do componente Guitars vai ser trocado pelo conteúdo da página Signup.

Esse é só um exemplo. A realidade do seu site pode ser bem diferente.